# Where are my resources hidden?

Tags: .net, resources

I have a program that contains a number of icons in an "Icons" folder (which are included in the project with Build Action=Resource).

In XAML I can access these icons with code such as `<Image Source="../Icons/name.png"/>` (".." because the XAML is in a different subfolder); however I want to use the same image in some WinForms code in the same project. Unfortunately,

```
GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Icons/name.png");
```

returns `null` and

```
GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

only lists a bunch of *.resources files (one for each .resx and one called *.g.resources). So how am I supposed to get the image stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assumed that since I included the images *directly* in my project that I could directly read them. But thanks to Jack's answer I was able to figure out that they are hidden inside a "resource file" named "ProgramName.g.resources" inside the assembly. To read the image it is necessary to load the resource file first, then search for the image file within the resource file.

`ResourceSet.GetObject` is case-sensitive, but the image path and filename were converted to lowercase for some reason, so I call `ToLowerInvariant` on the path name. Here's my solution:

```
private Stream GetGlobalResourceByPath(Assembly assembly, string path)
{
    string name = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(n => n.EndsWith(".g.resources")).First();
    Stream outerStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name);
    ResourceSet resources = new ResourceSet(outerStream);
    return resources.GetObject(path.ToLowerInvariant()) as UnmanagedMemoryStream;
}
```

I'm not sure how expensive it is to construct a `ResourceSet`. If it's expensive, and you want to retrieve multiple resources, then you should cache and re-use the `ResourceSet` object.

Please leave a message if you know why the images end up inside the *.g.resources file. Did Visual Studio choose this name? Is it theoretically possible to put images directly in an assembly, or can assemblies only contain "ResourceSets"?

Comment: I didn't bother with resource files when I wanted to include images, javascript, css etceteras.  I had them directly in the project with a build-action of `Embedded Resource` and therefore didn't have to mess around with resource sets whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

you can find some help from:

http://blog.devarchive.net/2007/12/net-assembly-resource-browser-test.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx

In the first link, you can find a way to get the resource that is type of UnmanagedMemoryStream, then you should find a way to convert the stream to the type you want.

Hope it helps you!

```
foreach (var resourceName in ThemeList.Current.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
                var resourceStream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
                ResourceSet resources = new ResourceSet(resourceStream);
                IDictionaryEnumerator enu = resources.GetEnumerator();
                while (enu.MoveNext())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(enu.Key); // Key is the resource name and Value is UnmanagedMemoryStream
                }
}
```